# Add empty row if key doesnt exist in list table

Tags: php, datatable

Dear People who already helped before.

I have an table what combines custom columns and custom data. But like you see some data is not under the right column.

[image]

My table code:

```
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <table class="table table-hover demo-table-dynamic table-responsive-block" id="tableWithDynamicRows">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
                                        echo '<th>'.$field['name'].'</th>';
                                    } ?>
                                    <th>Actie</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($dataList as $datas) {
                                            $values = getDataTableWithoutDatabase($datas, $list, 'datalist');
                                            foreach ($values as $value) {
                                                echo $value;
                                            }
                                        }  
                                    ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

My method that creates the table:

```
function getDataTableWithoutDatabase(array $columns, array $list, string $table) {

$i = 0;
$len = count($columns);
foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
    $field = '';
    if($key == array_key_first($list)) {
        $field .= '<tr>';
    }
    foreach ($list as $keys) {
        if($key != array_key_first($list) && empty($columns[$keys]) && $key != 'uid') {
            $field .= '<td class="v-align-middle"></td>';
        }
    }
    if($key != 'uid') {
        $field .= '<td class="v-align-middle">';
        $field .= '<p>' . $value . '</p>';
        $field .= '</td>';  
    }
    if($key == 'uid') {
        $last = '<td><a href="../'.$table.'edit?'.$table.'='. $value .'">Bewerken</a></td>';
    }
    if($i == $len - 1) {
        $field .= $last;
        $field .= '</tr>';
    }
    $fields[] = $field;
    $i++;
}
return $fields; 
}
```

The solution is. I want to have the right information under the right columns:
Below a sample what is in the variable `$columns`

[image]

`$list` contain:

```
['Voornaam','Achternaam','Initialen']
```

`$columns` contain:

```
array(4) {
  ["Voornaam"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["uid"]=>
  string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245f"
  ["Achternaam"]=>
  string(3) "Les"
  ["Initialen"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(4) {
  ["Voornaam"]=>
  string(6) "Simone"
  ["uid"]=>
  string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245g"
  ["Achternaam"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Initialen"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(4) {
  ["Voornaam"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["uid"]=>
  string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245l"
  ["Achternaam"]=>
  string(4) "Yül"
  ["Initialen"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(4) {
  ["Voornaam"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["uid"]=>
  string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245s"
  ["Achternaam"]=>
  string(3) "Mas"
  ["Initialen"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(4) {
  ["Voornaam"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["uid"]=>
  string(15) "gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn"
  ["Achternaam"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  ["Initialen"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: What is the `var_export()`'ed data contained in `$list`?  It is nowhere in your question.  All array data is best displayed in your question as text (not images) of the `var_export()` output.

Comment: I've added $list array

Comment: So there is a case-sensitivity issue too?  `achternaam` and `Achternaam`  Please fix your presented data for the `$columns` array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any point in making so many iterated calls of `array_key_first()` -- in fact, just use the known column names to dictate the order of data when generating the markup.  The final cell in each table row is `uid`, so just add that to the list of column names.

I have renamed many of your variables to make your script easier to follow.

I don't know just how dynamic this custom function will become.  I am using `http_build_query()` as a matter of best practice -- so that you always generate a valid query string, but if there will only be alphanumeric keys and values, then this can be reverted to your original technique of injectin directly into the url string.

There is no need to generate an array to return to the html table when you are just going to implode it anyhow.  In other words, just create a string, return it, and echo it.

Complete rewrite: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QaPNj))

```
function getDataTableWithoutDatabase(array $dataRow, array $columnNames, string $tableName) {
    $tableRow = '<tr>';
        foreach ($columnNames as $columnName) {
            $tableRow .= '<td class="v-align-middle">';
                if ($dataRow[$columnName]) {
                    $tableRow .= "<p>{$dataRow[$columnName]}</p>";
                }
            $tableRow .= '</td>';
        }
        $tableRow .= '<td><a href="../' . $tableName . 'edit?' . http_build_query([$tableName => $dataRow['uid']]) .'">Bewerken</a></td>';
    $tableRow .= '</tr>';
    return $tableRow;
}

$resultSet = [
    ['Voornaam' => '', 'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245f', 'Achternaam' => 'Les', 'Initialen' => ''],
    ['Voornaam' => 'Foo', 'uid' => 'fedcba098765432', 'Achternaam' => '', 'Initialen' => ''],
    ['Voornaam' => '', 'uid' => '1234567890abcde', 'Achternaam' => '', 'Initialen' => 'Bar'],
];

$fieldList = [['name' => 'Voornaam'], ['name' => 'Achternaam'], ['name' => 'Initialen']];
$list = array_column($fieldList, 'name');
?>

<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-hover demo-table-dynamic table-responsive-block" id="tableWithDynamicRows">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php echo '<th>' . implode('</th><th>', $list) . '</th>'; ?>
            <th>Actie</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            echo getDataTableWithoutDatabase($row, $list, 'datalist');
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Output (after retabbing the markup):

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-hover demo-table-dynamic table-responsive-block" id="tableWithDynamicRows">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Voornaam</th>
                <th>Achternaam</th>
                <th>Initialen</th>
                <th>Actie</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="v-align-middle"></td>
                <td class="v-align-middle"><p>Les</p></td>
                <td class="v-align-middle"></td>
                <td><a href="../datalistedit?datalist=7d1f4f8e906245f">Bewerken</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="v-align-middle"><p>Foo</p></td>
                <td class="v-align-middle"></td>
                <td class="v-align-middle"></td>
                <td><a href="../datalistedit?datalist=fedcba098765432">Bewerken</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="v-align-middle"></td>
                <td class="v-align-middle"></td>
                <td class="v-align-middle"><p>Bar</p></td>
                <td><a href="../datalistedit?datalist=1234567890abcde">Bewerken</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because if the `firstname` isn't present you do not add an empty `td` due to:

```
$key != array_key_first($list)
```

in

```
    foreach ($list as $keys) {
        if($key != array_key_first($list) && empty($columns[$keys])) {
            $field .= '<td class="v-align-middle"></td>';
        }
    }
```

This prevents a `firstname` column to be drawn if one is absent. Because it will always skip this, unless the `key` of the first column is actually present in the `column` array

Your codes prints:

```
foo  | bar | 15
bar2 | 24  |
bar3 |
```

Skipping that check should make it work, because it pads empty `td` from the left.

Comment: Thanks, almost done. The only thing what now is. if i have only a firstname, then i get not emtpy td on lastname and age :S

Comment: Now I get the following result: Firstname is under firstname, lastname is under age and if you only have a firstname you dont get any row under lastname or age.

Comment: I'm working right now (I'm a teacher). Will test this against my server later today!

Comment: Ok I've read you comment again. The key will look in a list and check if firstname isset if it not then add empty td. That is correct. But now the problem is that he give me a empty td on lastname and a td that is filled with lastname. The check on empty() doesnt work correctly

Comment: Only in my new update he doesnt fill the firstname. Because he overide it. :S

Comment: Can you answer my question again /

Comment: Sorry but a. this is not how SO works. New question is new post. and B. I can't make heads of tails of what you exactly want. What is the data you get from your DB, how is it formatted in the first function and what result (table) do you want from the second function?

Comment: I've edit my question so you can understand better the situation

Comment: Mouser can you look again ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the keys/column names match ...

```
public function getDataTableWithoutDatabase(array $columns, array $list) {
    $fields = [];
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        $field = '<tr>';
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $field .= '<td class="v-align-middle">';
            if(!empty($row[$column])) {
                $field .= '<p>' . $row[$column] . '</p>';
            }
            $field .= '</td>';
        }
        $field .= '</tr>';
        $fields[] = $field;
    }
    return $fields; 
}
```

This should output

```
| foo | bar  | 15 |
|     | bar2 | 24 |
|     | bar3 |    |
```

Comment: You don't have added the $key variable :S

Comment: Sorry, copy pasta. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks i'll check it again

Comment: I did make another small correction, and will add what I expect it to output.

Comment: Look at my update. I've added a new solution. Because when i do it in this method then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a PHP function that you can copy / paste in your code to replace the body of your function `getDataTableWithoutDatabase`:

```
function getDataTableWithoutDatabase(array $columns, array $list, string $tableName) {
    $response = '<tr>';

    foreach ($list as $i => $column) {
        $response .= '<td class="v-align-middle">';

        // I'm using "ucfirst" here since I see your "$columns" array has its keys
        // with their first letter in upper case. Change it if you need it.

        $columnName = ucfirst($column);

        if (isset($columns[$columnName])) {
            $response .= $columns[$columnName];
        }

        $response .= '</td>';
    }

    // Add the last column with the link.

    $response .= '<td><a href="../'.$tableName.'edit?'.urlencode($tableName).'='.urlencode($columns['uid']).'">Bewerken</a></td>';

    $response .= '</tr>';

    return $response;
}
```

The only field I don't see in your question is the one present in the image called **Actie**, but I assume it will be present on *$list*.

Here you can try this function online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e50b76de77c0a763ea769bd13788572f92f3a14